# Excel formula, always include 2 decimal value on right

Tags: excel, excel-formula, decimal

I am concatenating multiple cells together which the values are numbers with 2 decimal places, what I want to happen is to merge all the values but has the fix output like If the amount is 100 --> becomes 100.00 then 10000 in the output file. If the amount is 99.50 --> It can be inputted as 99.50 and 9950 in the output file.

please see image below for reference.[image]

Comment: Is this a Homework question?  Why don't you tell us what your Current Output formula is?

Comment: Do you really want to multiply your numbers by 100 to eliminate the decimal point?  And what would be the logic/motivation behind doing that?

Comment: hmmm... could be

Comment: We are trying to merge those cells into a reference number where that value will be included between the ID Number-Usercode-Amount-Date-AccountType

Comment: so, you basically want to multiply each input by 100 and then concatenate the results...

Comment: and we will convert that into text file and upload into the system and if the validation is correct then thats an A. I am actually done with the most of the php, vba thing but I am not really familiar with excel

Comment: @Profex It doesnt multiply anything, I just want to concatenate the 2 cells into 1 like what I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=substitute(text(c2, "0.00"), ".", "")&substitute(text(d2, "0.00"), ".", "")
```

Comment: The OP also appears to want to multiply the decimals by 100 first, before concatenating.  Actually, it wasn't clear to me what the OP really wants, hence I did not answer.

Comment: @Profex yes it is but we don't study excel so I am not very familiar with this, it may be very simple for you guys but I'm sorry I am not that very familiar with the syntax in this stuff, if you are thinking that I just want an easy answer to my question, it is not. this is just a small part which I am not familiar that is why I am asking for help.

Comment: it is not like I copy and paste that string and then poof! Im done, anyways thank you for your concern @Profex

Comment: @Jeeped thank you for your help I will just figure out how to include this on the formula. God speed

Answer (score 0):

Your lucky I have to go leave...

`=C2*100&D2*100`

worst case, you might want to use `Trunc()` to be 100% that you didn't have a 3rd decimal place somewhere

`=TRUNC(C2*100,0)&TRUNC(D2*100,0)`